# How to do Virtual IP Setup in Mac OS X?

Tags: load-balancing, mac, virtualization, operating-system

I have two Apache Load Balancer setup on two different systems, for example 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 IP addresses.

Now I want to configure Virtual IP in another system (127.0.0.3) and all the requests will be send to this virtual IP. Then internally it will forward the requests to Active Load Balancer machine. If the active Load Balancer go down, it will internally switch to passive load balancer.

This needs to be done to achieve high availability of the system.

I don't have much idea about Virtual IP setup, so any help here will be appreciated. Can we do it from another installation of Apache and some configuration in the apache server?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out TunTap: http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/